# How to preserve native IOS and Android code changes in Ionic build process

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

In our Ionic project we have created a few actual native views for IOS and Android. We did this by adding them to the Xcode and Android Studio projects them selves.

We are now having portability problems getting it to run on another machine. It suggests doing a `ionic platform rm ios` and `ionic platform add ios`

By doing this all the custom views and functionality applied to the projects directly will be overwritten.

What is the proper way to correct this problem? I understand its likely a plugin, but how would you go about creating a plugin which is an actual native view?

Comment: Take a look at an existing plugin that uses custom native views such as [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps)